# In Python, I want to subtract a time period from within a time period

Tags: python, time, calculation

I want to calculate hours of work during a day, and subtract lunchtime from that time. So somebody clocks in at 8:00, takes a lunch from 12:00 to 12:30, and finish at 16:00.
Lunchtime is configured in a settings table, with start-time and end-time.

So in a nutshell I want to calculate this:

endtime minus starttime = n hours:minutes of work, minus lunchtime (= 12:30 - 12:00 = 30 minutes)

How can I calculate this in Python without making this a hardcoded thing?
Help would be much appreciated

cheers

Comment: Do you have specific time formats in mind?  Is the input in String, or seconds?  Have you tried anything yet?  Note, if your times are start, end, lunchstart, and lunchend.. you could make do with (lunchstart-start) + (end-lunchend)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please note that this is not a code-writing or tutorial site, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] including sample input, sample output, and _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research

Comment: Try looking at the `datetime` module.  This would allow you to do things like `total_worked = (clocks_out - clocks_in) - (lunch_end - lunch_start)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Python datetime:

```py
import datetime as dt

def work_time(start, end, lunch=[], format_='%H:%M'):
    """ Calculate the hours worked in a day.
    """
    start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(start, format_)
    end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(end, format_)

    if lunch:
        lunch_start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(lunch[0], format_)
        lunch_end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(lunch[1], format_)
        lunch_duration = lunch_end_dt - lunch_start_dt
    else:
        lunch_duration = dt.timedelta(0)

    elapsed = end_dt - start_dt - lunch_duration
    hours = elapsed.seconds / 3600

    return hours
```

```py
>>> work_time('8:00', '16:00', lunch=['12:00', '12:30'])
7.5
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for datetime provides more information on specific formatting and how to use timedeltas to perform operations on datetime and time objects.

Comment: Looking at your solution, my mistake was trying to work with timeobjects instead of datetime, which are far more easy to work with. Sorry for not providing more info, but the stuff I had so far, was hardly representable as a good example. This I can work with. Cheers!

Comment: If you're happy with the answer mark it as correct to conclude the question :)